# i can't use properly ies lgiht

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

[image]i can't use properly ies light, all light are showing this image type. can you help me. i am very tried. please check interior image , that very nice ies light but i can't do in blender.

of course Render engine cycles. 
[image]

[![but can't to do properly ies light , all ies showing image type]

Comment: please any man , help me

Comment: i was try this video instruction follow but not work. https://youtu.be/isa-4XQ2Tj8

Comment: What is your question really? That is very vague, could you elaborate on what you did and how it failed?

Comment: Dear friend, i can't create actually ies light .

Comment: are you seen cegaton .

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this effect. If i understood you

[image]

Install the Addon from [here](https://gist.github.com/AngryLoki/4364512)

Download the ies light pack Free from [here](http://www.mrcad.com/download-free-ies-lights/)

After activate addon File-> import-> ies

Select the 3d where u want ies light should be. 
Navigate the ies light from the pack.

If u want to control the light open the N panel and at last Lamp Properties you can adjust the settings.

Answer (score -3):

This problem is solve . Thank you for yours help.

[image: i was use addons and ies but my think it's not actual correct]

[image: i was use node editor ( copy form another work) my think this is pefect]

Comment: i was use node editor . point light with node editor. this is  perfect. last image

Comment: Dear sir, can sent me your blend file.

Comment: To make this a useful answer, please describe in detail what you did.